# Find anagrams in a list

Tags: scala

> Write a program that, given a word and a list of possible anagrams,
>   selects the correct sublist.
>
> Given `"listen"` and a list of candidates like `"enlists" "google" "inlets" "banana"` the program should return a list containing `"inlets"`.

Here is my solution:

```
class Anagram(word: String) {
  val sorted_word = word.toLowerCase.sorted
  val origin_word = word.toLowerCase

  def matches(words: Seq[String]) = {
    words.filter(w => w.toLowerCase.sorted == sorted_word && w.toLowerCase != origin_word)
  }

}
```

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/HeeL/696ac4629d36c4ee3249) with specs.

Comment: Just as a general note, I'd recommend avoiding too many questions in a row, the reviews you get from one question can often be applied to other pieces of code you write as well.

Answer (score 4):

Looks good! Just one little thing that I, personally would do to remove one `.toLowerCase` call per item: `map` it first. So, instead of calling `.toLowerCase` in the `filter`, you can do this:

```
words.map(w => w.toLowerCase)
     .filter(w => w.sorted == sorted_word && w != origin_word)
```

You've also got a random newline before the end of the `class`.

Aside from that little niggle, it looks good! There's... really not much I can say. It's short code.

Comment: Is this a good idea to have a map and a filter separately? It goes through the list two times then

Comment: @HeeL My thinking was that, because the `toLowerCase` was applied only once, it would save time -- AFAIK iteration is faster than iteration _and_ mutation.

Comment: @HeeL I am no Scala expert, but there is a possibility to have them be lazy transformers, which would be quite efficient, see http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_42.html for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you call this several times, it will be more efficient to put all of `words` into a `Map[String, List[String]]` where the keys are sorted

```
words.groupBy(_.sorted)
```

Which allows you to get all the words in a simple lookup from there on in.

Answer (score 1):

**CASE CLASS**

I would change `Anagram` to a `case class`. One reason for this change is more concise object declaration, e.g:

```
  val a = Anagram("silent")
  // as opposed to ...
  val b = new Anagram("inlets")
```

Another benefit is that `wordOrigin` automatically becomes a field for any `Anagram` object (this is also possible with standard class declaration by prepending `val` to the front of the parameter.) These two examples don't really demonstrate the full utility of `case classes` so if you'd like to learn more check out this [link](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html).

**STYLE**

Current Scala dogma utilizes camelCase. So I've swapped `word_origin` and `word_sorted` for `wordSorted` and `wordOrigin`. I also added a return type to your method `matches`.

**A QUICK NOTE ON TYPES**

One of the cool things about types is that they allow you to constrain your program. For example, as your `matches` method currently stands there are over twenty different collection types (of the mutable and immutable variety) that may be passed in for `words` (see these [inheritance graphs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/collections.html)). Long story short, I swapped `Seq` for `List`.

**STRING OPERATIONS**

Finally, to get around calling `toLowerCase` I utilized a method from [StringOps](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps) called `equalsIgnoreCase` which returns `true` if the caller and the input `String` are equal (regardless of capitalization), false otherwise. To be honest I only changed this bit to show you another possibility.

```
case class Anagram(wordOrigin: String) {
  val wordSorted = wordOrigin.sorted

  def matches(xs: List[String]): List[String] = {
    xs.filter(w => 
      w.sorted.equalsIgnoreCase(wordSorted) && !w.equalsIgnoreCase(wordOrigin) 
    )
  }
}
```

**NAMES**

Whoops, one more thing. I think I would also rename your class from `Anagram` to `Word` or something similar and rename the method from `matches` to `anagrams`. That is:

```
case class Word(...) {
  // ...
  def anagrams(...) = { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why do you prefer List over its ancestors? In the above code you are not making use of any features that List provides and Iterable does not.